# Bilinear form is non degenerate if and only if $f$ is bijective

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $(V,\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ a finite dimensional euclidean vector space and $f\in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$. Then defiene a bilinear form on $V$ $\beta(v,w)=\langle v,f(w)\rangle$

1. Prove that $\beta $ is non degenerate iff $f$ is bijective.

---

According to the definition of non degenerate (what I've learnd), if $\beta$ is non degenerate in first variable, when $$\forall w\in V\ \beta(v,w)=0\Rightarrow v=0$$
and if $\beta$ is non degeneratte in second variable, when $$\forall v\in V\ \beta(v,w)=0\Rightarrow w=0$$

But how can I get the bijectivity of $f$ with this definition?
$$\forall v\in V\ \beta(v,w)=\langle v,f(w)\rangle\ \Rightarrow\ w=0,f(w)=0$$ Besides I tried to prove f is injective or surjective, since the linear function f is totally in $V$, then $f$ is bijective. Could you please give me some hints, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
(f:\text{not invertible} \iff\beta: \text{degenerate}) 
\equiv
(f:\text{invertible} \iff\beta: \text{non-degenerate})
$$

### In the 1st argument

- $\beta: \text{degenerate} \implies f:\text{not invertible}$

If $\beta$ is degenerate then there is a nonzero vector $v \in V$ such that for all $x \in V$
$$
0 = \beta(v,x) = \langle v, f(x)\rangle \implies \text{Im}f \subset \{v\}^\perp \subset V,
$$
so the image is proper subspace and $f$ is not surjective.

- $f:\text{not invertible} \implies \beta: \text{degenerate}$

If $f$ is not invertible then its image is proper subspace $\text{Im} f \subsetneq V$, and wlog non trivial, then its orthogonal complement $W=(\text{Im} f)^\perp$ is nonempty. Take any $v \in W$ then for all $y \in V$
$$
\beta(v,y) := \langle v, f(y) \rangle = 0.
$$

### In the 2nd Argument

- $\beta: \text{degenerate} \implies f:\text{not invertible}$

If $\beta$ is degenerate then there is a nonzero vector $x \in V$ such that for all $w \in V$
$$
0 = \beta(w,x) = \langle w, f(x)\rangle \implies f(x) = 0,
$$
**by the non-degeneracy of the inner product**. It follows that the kernel is nontrivial and $f$ is not injective.

- $f:\text{not invertible} \implies \beta: \text{degenerate}$

Its kernel is not trivial and so there is a nonzero vector $y \in \ker f$ such that for all $v \in V$ the bilinear form
$$
\beta(v,y) := \langle v, f(y) \rangle = \langle v, 0 \rangle = 0
$$
is degenerate.

Comment: This is brilliant, I've never thought to prove it by contradiction and f is invertible iff f is bijective. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry!, It seems that I had to distinguish between the first and second argument (non)degeneracy

Comment: But I think if a bilinear form on finite dimensional vector space is non-degenerate in one argument then it is non-degenerate in the other, one may prove that